# Converting an image to a specific byte format

Tags: c, image, format, bmp, raw

So, I'm using an API to display a picture and it requires me to insert the actual bytes from the picture and not any specific file. There are a few listed examples, where they display pictures through hex bytes in a C vector, and the format they have is as follows:

If the picture has x width and y height and is mono color, the amount of bytes is exactly x times y. If the picture is RGB, the amount of bytes is exactly x times y times 3 (which I assume is one byte for R, one for G, one for B).

I'm trying to display an arrow which I've tried to convert to BMP and RAW, but I know very little about image formatting and it obviously didn't work, as those files always ended up with way too many bytes. Is there some sort of converter that I can hopefully make or find to convert a picture into that hex C vector, or am I over complicating all of this?

Thanks,
José Almeida

Comment: The BMP-fileformat is very easy to implement, because it is (most times) uncompressed and has very few overhead: https://www.fileformat.info/format/bmp/egff.htm PS don't use vectors, just use a stream of bytes, aka malloc(); PPS if you won't use 24 bits per pixel, you probably have to deal with colour pallets or bit masks, which you probably don't want to do, because it's overcomplicating things.

Comment: PPPS a WORD consists of two BYTES. One of those bytes is called most significant byte, while the other byte is called least significant. The byte which is most significant carriers the data of the mathematical most significant numerals and vice versa. It is very important to know, that on most computers, but not on all computers, the least significant byte is first stored within memory and so also on hard disks or flash memory. So when you read a binary file, like a BMP, you've to remind this. Because 0x253A in memory is in real 3A25h. Same mechanic applies to a DWORD, which is 2 WORD long.

Comment: Sorry about my shallow knowledge on the issue, but how would I go around converting a jpg/png to a BMP and removing that overhead? There seem to be around 1072 bytes (that's around 6%) too many on the picture I'm trying to convert. As for the vector/stream of bytes part, I don't know why I would do it differently from the actual API example, which uses a vector. I can display the pictures provided in the example in the API, but I can't for some reason view them anywhere else other than the device the apps run on

Comment: The task you wish to do is not easily done. You've to invest much time in investigating how actual computers work. A picture file most times consist of two file parts. First part is the file header, second part is the bitmap data. The first part specifies the exact bitmap and file dimensions, the second part is the actual raw bitmap data. Read the link I've provided and try to use **BMP Version 3 (Microsoft Windows 3.x)** with 24bit colour format. This is one of the common BMP formats. It has a 54byte long file header and the remaining data is the bitmap data. Read the entire link! ;-)